# Audio player in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to implement audio(Media player) in RecyclerView but issue is it is crashing in first place ,I have tried to implement code on bindView holder but it took all resource which cause app hang and crash also i have tried to do it in another way still it is crashing

I am trying to make a chat app like whatsapp but it does not work the same way i am trying

```
public class AdapterNewSingleChat extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    List<PojoNewChatMessage> data;
    SharedPreferences shdUSer;
    Context context;
    DatabaseReference userRef;
    private static final int MSG_UPDATE_SEEK_BAR = 1845;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    private Handler uiUpdateHandler;
    private int playingPosition;
    private SenderViewAudio playingHolder;

    public AdapterNewSingleChat(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        shdUSer = context.getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        userRef = UserFirebase.databaseReference().child("User");
        this.playingPosition = -1;
    }

    public void setData(List<PojoNewChatMessage> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        if (i == R.layout.single_sent_message_text) {
            return new SenderViewMessage(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_sent_message_text, viewGroup, false));
        } else if (i == R.layout.single_received_message_text) {
            return new ReciverViewMessage(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_received_message_text, viewGroup, false));

        } else if (i == R.layout.single_sent_message_audio) {
            return new SenderViewAudio(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_sent_message_audio, viewGroup, false));

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof SenderViewMessage) {
            ((SenderViewMessage) viewHolder).txtSenderMessage.setText(data.get(i).getMessage());
            ((SenderViewMessage) viewHolder).txtSenderTime.setText(data.get(i).getTime());
        }
        if (viewHolder instanceof ReciverViewMessage) {
            ((ReciverViewMessage) viewHolder).txtReciverMessage.setText(data.get(i).getMessage());
            ((ReciverViewMessage) viewHolder).txtReciverTime.setText(data.get(i).getTime());

            userRef.child(data.get(i).getFrom()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        ((ReciverViewMessage) viewHolder).txtReciverName.setText(name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

        if (viewHolder instanceof SenderViewAudio){
            if (i == playingPosition) {
                playingHolder = ((SenderViewAudio)viewHolder);
                // this view holder corresponds to the currently playing audio cell
                // update its view to show playing progress
                updatePlayingView();
            } else {
                // and this one corresponds to non playing
                updateNonPlayingView(((SenderViewAudio)viewHolder));
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (data.get(position).getType().equals("txt")) {

            if (data.get(position).getFrom().equals(shdUSer.getString("user_id", ""))) {
                return R.layout.single_sent_message_text;
            } else {
                return R.layout.single_received_message_text;
            }
        }
        if (data.get(position).getType().equals("audio")) {
            if (data.get(position).getFrom().equals(shdUSer.getString("user_id", ""))) {
                return R.layout.single_sent_message_audio;
            } else {
                return R.layout.single_recieved_message_audio;
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }

    public class ReciverViewAudio extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTime, txtName;
        ImageView imgPlay, imgPause;
        ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ReciverViewAudio(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_audio_reciver_text_time);
            imgPlay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_single_messeage_reciver_audio_play);
            imgPause = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_single_messeage_reciver_audio_pause);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_single_reciver_messeage_audio);
            txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_reciver_text_name);
        }
    }

    public class SenderViewAudio extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        TextView txtTime;
        ImageView imgPlay, imgPause;
        SeekBar sbProgress;

        public SenderViewAudio(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_single_messeage_audio_time);
            imgPlay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_single_messeage_audio_play);
            imgPause = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_single_messeage_audio_pause);
            sbProgress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_single_messeage_audio);
            sbProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getAdapterPosition() == playingPosition) {
                // toggle between play/pause of audio
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            } else {
                // start another audio playback
                playingPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (null != playingHolder) {
                        updateNonPlayingView(playingHolder);
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
                playingHolder = this;
                startMediaPlayer(data.get(playingPosition).getMessage());
            }
            updatePlayingView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    }

    public class ReciverViewMessage extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtReciverMessage, txtReciverName, txtReciverTime;

        public ReciverViewMessage(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtReciverMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_reciver_text_message);
            txtReciverName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_reciver_text_name);
            txtReciverTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_reciver_text_time);
        }
    }

    public class SenderViewMessage extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtSenderMessage, txtSenderTime;

        public SenderViewMessage(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtSenderMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sender_text_message);
            txtSenderTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sender_message_time);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        if (playingPosition == holder.getAdapterPosition()) {
            // view holder displaying playing audio cell is being recycled
            // change its state to non-playing
            if (playingHolder!=null)
            updateNonPlayingView(playingHolder);
            playingHolder = null;
        }
    }


    //==================AUDIO=======================

    private void updatePlayingView() {
        playingHolder.sbProgress.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        playingHolder.sbProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        playingHolder.sbProgress.setEnabled(true);
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            uiUpdateHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_SEEK_BAR, 100);
            playingHolder.imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            playingHolder.imgPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            uiUpdateHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_SEEK_BAR);
            playingHolder.imgPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            playingHolder.imgPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void updateNonPlayingView(SenderViewAudio holder) {
        if (holder == playingHolder) {
            uiUpdateHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_SEEK_BAR);
        }
        holder.sbProgress.setEnabled(false);
        holder.sbProgress.setProgress(0);
        playingHolder.imgPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        playingHolder.imgPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void startMediaPlayer(String audioResId) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioResId);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                releaseMediaPlayer();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (null != playingHolder) {
            updateNonPlayingView(playingHolder);
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        playingPosition = -1;
    }
}
```

Previously i have tried this in bind view holder

```
if (viewHolder instanceof SenderViewAudio) {
    ((SenderViewAudio) viewHolder).txtTime.setText(data.get(i).getTime());
    ((SenderViewAudio) viewHolder).imgPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                player.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(data.get(i).getMessage()));
                player.prepare();
                player.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
            ((SenderViewAudio) viewHolder).imgPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((SenderViewAudio) viewHolder).imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    ((SenderViewAudio) viewHolder).imgPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            ((SenderViewAudio) viewHolder).imgPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((SenderViewAudio) viewHolder).imgPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you want to implement playing video in `RecyclerView` than you should consider caching video first and then play it. That is the way to avoid crashes on `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: how i can do it ?? please provide brief solution if possible

Comment: i have to do this for  audio and video file

Comment: Why not try with `ExoPlayer` from Google it has caching feature, not sure is it enabled by default but it can be enabled if not, and it is actually `MediasPlayer` alternative.

Comment: yes it is but custom views are issue and it is good for instagram type vide player still iam reading about this

Comment: Your video should play on press not by default?

Comment: Anyway I think you didn't take best approach, why didn't just create layouts and `hide/show` depending is message text, video or audio.

Comment: I have tried to do the same feature with Audio files like Whatsapp. I have made a Service with MediaPlayer that sendBroadcast of the currentPosition of the player. From that i notifyDataItemPosition to show the UI updates

Answer (score -1):

Don't play the music into the RecyclerView
do it on the activity or the fragment by using  an interface for this in the onClick event